# How to delete all rows with a specific value

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, filtering, subset

This might be quite simple, but I have looked at answers across this site without finding a solution. I have a dataframe and I would like to remove all observations equal to 1. In my original df there is more than 90 columns.

I have tried with lapply functions and by filtering but I cannot make it work:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = c('0','1', '0', '1', '1'),
                 x2 = c('1','0', '1', '1', '0'),
                 x3 = c('1','0', '1', '1', '1'))

df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) subset(df, x==0 ))
df<- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) subset(df, x==0 )))
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) df[!(df$x ==1),])

library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(!all(df == 1))
df<-df[!(df ==1),]
```

My expected output is

```
 x2 x3
0   0
```

Comment: What should happen if there are missing values, e.g. a row is `c(1, 1, NA, 1)`?

Comment: Good question. I haven't checked data for NA's but that could be a posibility. If possible, I would like to keep the NA values, as the purpose is for testing

Comment: How should actually your expected output look like?

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf, I have added expected output in the question

Comment: Column `x3` has more `0` than the actual data, how would that happen?

Comment: You're right. I have changed the output. It looks silly but makes sense in a larger df

Comment: Can you explain how do you get the expected output shown? which are these 2 zeroes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you use `data.table`:

```
DT<-as.data.table(df)
ans<-DT[,lapply(.SD, function(x){subset(x,x!="1")})]
ans
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! It works fine on the small df I created for this purpose, but when I try it on my original df I get this error; Item 2 has 199987 rows but longest item has 200000; recycled with remainder.Item 3 has 183095 rows but longest item has 200000; recycled with remainder.Item 4 has 51291 rows but longest item has 200000; and so on . Have you seen that before? all my variables are chr as in this example, if they are numeric, I get the same error

Comment: Are you sure it is not a warning? When I use the reverse filter example above `DT[,lapply(.SD, function(x){subset(x,x=="1")})]` then I get a similar warning. In that case both x1 and x2 has three rows `x== "1"`respectively, while x3 has four rows `x== "1"`. The corresponding output is a 4x3 `data.table` with all values equal to "1"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowSums` to select rows where there exists a single value other than 1.

```
df[rowSums(df != 1, na.rm = TRUE) > 0, ]
#Another way
#df[rowSums(df == 1, na.rm = TRUE) != ncol(df), ]

#  x1 x2 x3
#1  0  1  1
#2  1  0  0
#3  0  1  1
#4  1  0  1
```

Or using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter_all(any_vars(. != 1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But with these solutions I still have rows/columns that include '1'. , I need to exclude all values of '1'/ keep all values with '0' (and NA if possible) in the dataframe?

Comment: Am I missing something, or is this solution still returning observations == 1?

Comment: @MetteFoss According to your question `I would like to remove all observations equal to 1 across all columns` This answer removes row 4 from `df` because it has all 1's. If this is not what you want please clarify it by updating your post with the expected output. Also include a case with `NA`'s so that it is clear what you want.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The point was that I needed the value one to be removed from the whole dataframe and not just one column. I have edited the question 

Comment: @MetteFoss Can you please show your expected output for the example to avoid confusion.

Comment: I have added it now @RonakShah. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could keep those rows which `var`iance is not zero. When we use `%in%`, rows with missing values will be kept.

```
df
#     x1 x2 x3
# 1    0  1  1
# 2    1  0  0
# 3 <NA>  1  1
# 4    1  1  1
# 5    1  0  1

df[!apply(df, 1, var) %in% 0, ]
#     x1 x2 x3
# 1    0  1  1
# 2    1  0  0
# 3 <NA>  1  1
# 5    1  0  1
```

---

*Data:*

I've added a missing in row 3.

```
df <- structure(list(x1 = c("0", "1", NA, "1", "1"), x2 = c("1", "0", 
"1", "1", "0"), x3 = c("1", "0", "1", "1", "1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

```
df[df == 1] <- 0
```

Output:

```
 x1    x2     x3
 50    0      0     
 0     50     50        
 10    0      0     
 0     0      NA        
 0     100    0
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame('x1' = c('50','1', '10', '1', '1'), "x2" = 
c('1','50', '1', '1', '100'), "x3" = c('1','50', '1', NA, '1'))
```

Comment: Thank you. No, I am looking for a way to filter the values out of the df, not changing them. But it is nice to know that it iis possible to change all the values in a df like this 